# Les formations « smart cities » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, prépositions, formulation-idiomatique, ponctuation

> [...s'accompagnent [...] de nouvelles formations « **smart cities** »
>   dans les écoles d'ingénieurs de la ville.](https://www.lapresse.ca/affaires/techno/201904/12/01-5221921-dijon-integre-le-club-ferme-des-villes-intelligentes.php)

On fait référence à la [*ville intelligente*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26544297). Comment formule-t-on clairement et naturellement cette phrase (préposition, nombre, absence ou présence de guillemets etc.) pour éviter complètement l'emploi du terme de langue anglaise ?

Comment: En le voyant dans l'article, j'ai cru que le nom de ce projet essayait de créer un verb avec "Dijon" (je dijon, il dijon, ON DIJON), mais en cherchant un peu j'ai vu que le "on" resemble au symbole pour démarrer les appareils électriques ("boot/power up/power **ON**."  Pas bête du tout comme nom, mais en l'entendant à l'oral, je ne peux pas m'empêcher de penser à "On Disjoncte"! (Anyway, I see potential ambiguity problems with just about any adjective used to describe such cities, at least in English, for if one takes "smart city" literally, it could mean any city that didn't vote for trump.)

Comment: @PapaPoule _Dijon allumée_ aurait été fort excellent à mon avis mais il semble que l'effet Chateaubriand dure plus longtemps qu'une DEL.

Comment: @Fólkvangr L'expression n'est pas « incorrecte » parce qu'elle est composée d'un mot anglais. Inutile peut-être, comme ta réponse aurait pu le démontrer. Par ailleurs l'extrait est significatif, c'est une dépêche de l'AFP, c'est reproduit partout, incluant dans un journal canadien tel que présenté ici. Stp réintroduis ta réponse afin de pouvoir nuancer ton propos.

Answer (score 1):

« smart cities » est ici utilisé pour qualifier les nouvelles formations sur les villes intelligentes. S'il s'agit du terme utilisé par les écoles d'ingénieurs pour qualifier leurs formations, il n'y a pas de raison de vouloir traduire.

Toutefois, s'il le fallait, j'écrirai : « s'accompagnent de nouvelles formations sur les villes intelligentes dans les écoles d'ingénieurs de la ville. »

Comment: Voir [ceci](https://www.bsb-education.com/?L=0), le Burgundy School of Business qui « lead for change » où tu peux visiter le « center for arts & cultural management » ou t'intéresser au « school of wine and spirits business » ou admirer l'« entreprenerial garden » en te demandand qui sont les « BSB alumni » et y référer avec le hashtag « weareBSB », tu peux t'abonner à la _newsletter_ ou relaxer au « learning center » ou dans un des espaces de « co-working » ou jeter un coup d'oeil au « career booster » en scandant « We are BSB ». Si on écoutait les écoles clientélistes on parlerait anglais.

Comment: Je suis pas tout à fait d'accord. Effectivement, à trop utiliser d'anglais, on détruit le français. Genre "lead for change". Là, il manque le sujet et t'as une phrase. Là, s'il s'agit du nom de la formation, il n'y pas trop d'intérêt à le changer. Mais je suis tout à fait d'accord sur l'emploi abusif de l'anglais.

Comment: Mais c'est ça le pépin, il ne s'agit pas du nom d'une formation mais bien du sujet de la formation. En effet pourquoi nommer une formation avec une langue étrangère plutôt que d'indiquer en quoi elle consiste ? Il me faut penser en anglais pour le percevoir comme un nom (_smart cities training_) et même là je ne suis pas certain que ce soit clair. Ça pourrait être le titre d'un cours (Les « smart cities ») mais en apport de qualification de _formation_, c'est étrange. Je compare ça à _energy star_, c'est pas un appareil _energy star_, c'est un appareil qui se conforme à cette norme.

Answer (score 1):

Le vieux-jeu papapoule que je suis, je traite de "gadget" beaucoup des choses que mes poussins trouvent "essentielles" et donc je suis pas mal tenté de proposer ["Ville Gadget"](http://formation.djehouti.com/cfj2014/projet03/issy.html) comme réponse (via *formation.djehouti.com*).

Mais même moi, je me résigne à reconnaître que les gadgets d'aujourd'hui seront les équipements standards de demain et du premier paragraphe de l'article sur Issy-les-Moulineaux (le lien en haut), j'emprunte et propose la notion de "numérique" pour arriver à ["Ville Numerique"](https://www.namur.be/fr/ma-ville/vie-politique/declaration-de-politique-communale/archives/ville-numerique-ou-ville-intelligente-1), qui est le terme que la ville Belge de Namur a choisi comme titre pour [cette Déclaration de Politique Communale](https://www.namur.be/fr/ma-ville/vie-politique/declaration-de-politique-communale/archives/ville-numerique-ou-ville-intelligente-1/namur-ville-numerique.pdf) (both via *namur.be/fr*).

> Les efforts d'équipement s'accompagnent de la création d'une chaire
>   universitaire sur [la nature de] la cité du futur et la gouvernance
>   des données à l'université de Bourgogne, et de nouvelles formations «
>   villes numeriques » dans les écoles d'ingénieurs de la ville.

---

(Although I [commented elsewhere parenthetically](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/34761/les-formations-smart-cities#comment71191_34761) that I thought that just about any adjective, in English at least, might cause confusion in this context [e.g., "smart city" could mean one that was full of smart people], I now think that this potential ambiguity could perhaps be avoided by using a term whose literal sense is more closely related to the computer age [e.g., "ville numerique" in French or at least ["digital city"](https://www.enelx.com/en/questions-and-answers/ecity/what-does-digital-city-mean) in English] [from *enelx.com*].)